# Logic issues with numberOfItemsInSection:

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to make my own version of this tutorial here (UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell): http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell

I'm having difficulties getting the correct count of UICollectionViewCells in each UITableViewCell:

[image]

The first cell is correct, it should have two UICollectionViewCells inside the UICollectionView (which of course, is inside a UITableViewCell). The second is what is throwing me up. Every time I make a new save in Core Data, it will add it to the previous cells. The second cell should have one UICollectionViewCell, not two UICollectionViewCells.

Here's my code (the code for AFTableViewCell & AFIndexedCollectionView can be found on the above tutorial link):

The numberOfItemsInSection: for the UICollectionView embedded in the UITableViewCell:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(AFIndexedCollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{ 
NSIndexPath *indexPath;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Group" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *urlDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"url" ascending:NO];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = nil;

sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:urlDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

NSString *temp = [fetchedObjects description];

NSArray *tempArg = [temp componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

return [tempArg count];
}
```

The numberOfSectionsInTableView: for the main UITableView:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = nil;

NSIndexPath *section;

sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section.section];

return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]; 
}
```

The NSFetchedResultsController:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController 
{ 
TBAppDelegate *delegate = (TBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

self.managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = nil;

fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = nil;

entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Group" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:INFINITY];

NSSortDescriptor *urlDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = nil;

sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:urlDescriptor, nil];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *frc = nil;

frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];

[frc setDelegate:self];

[self setFetchedResultsController:frc];

return frc;

}
```

The UITableView cellForRowAtIndexpath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

AFTableViewCell *cell = (AFTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[AFTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

return cell;   
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]objectAtIndex:section];
```

instead of

```
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

in your `- (NSInteger)collectionView:(AFIndexedCollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section`   function on line 10

It seems the IndexPath local variable is not initialized in this function. You can get section from the parameter passed.

and you haven't initialized `section` local variable in your

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

function.

If you do not initialize this variables and use them, they return a garbage value or crashes the program. be careful in these kind of access.